# Unnecessary newline when using grep with a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep, echo

I have setup like this:

```
    #read a list of files
    tr -d \\015 < sample.txt | while IFS=, read -r NAME
        do
            #grep for lines and do stuff
            for VAR in $(grep '.*: {$' $NAME)
                do
                do some stuff
                done
        done
```

Problem is this. It doesn't work, because the for VAR in $(grep '.*: {$' $NAME) adds an unnecessary space and newline to its results.

If I echo $VAR I get the following:

```
    blahblahblah: 
    {
```

Now consider this code:

```
    #read a list of files
    tr -d \\015 < sample.txt | while IFS=, read -r NAME
        do
            VAR=$(grep '.*: {$' $NAME)
            echo $VAR
        done
```

If I echo $VAR here I get:

```
    blahblahblah: {
```

Why do I get the extra newline in the first example?

Comment: `for VAR in ...` iterates over *words*, not lines, so "blahblahblah:" and "{" are treated as separate items. You can change the definition of "word" to be more like a line, but really you should use another `while read` loop. See [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Also, you should almost always double-quote variable references (to avoid weird parsing), and use lower- or mixed-case variable names (to avoid conflicts with the all-caps names with special meanings).

Comment: ....see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/1745001